# Weight measurement with real-time time stamping using the Kern KB 3600-2N precision balance

Tags: real-time, scale, measurement, timestamping

I'm a PhD student, and as part of my research, I'm testing devices that simulate the pressing of a finger into buttons. I'm currently working on collecting weight data (in grams) with real-time time stamps from different buttons. To do this, I'm using a Kern KB 3600-2N scale on which I place my buttons one by one. Here's the link to the scale user manual: https://dok.kern-sohn.com/manuals/files/English/572-573-KB-DS-FKB-FCB-KBJ-BA-e-1774.pdf

I want to record in real time the weight applied by the participants for each button. To do this, I've set up the scale to display the scale data (weight in grams) in real time in PuTTY.
I connected my Kern scale and, as explained in the scale's user manual, succeeded in configuring it to obtain data in "AUTOPRINT PC (Continuous data output)" mode.

But I don't know how to get the timestamp in real time as well. Is this possible with the Kern KB 3600-2N scale I have? If so, how do I go about it? With which software?

Thanks in advance for your help.